# Retrieving data based with a where clause in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, where-clause

Tried storing messages using firebase database. While retrieving the data using the reference messages i get all the messages.

```
firebase.database().ref('messages').on('child_added', function (snapshot{ 
    console.log(snapshot.val() 
}
```

How can i add a filter to it to receive only the messages sent by that particular user. I need the messages sent and received by the user ids I provide

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform a query:

```
firebase.database().ref('messages').orderByChild("user").equalTo("john").on('value', ((snapshot) =>{ 
    console.log(snapshot.val());
}
```

Assuming you have the following database:

```
messages
   id
    user    : john
    message : message_here
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data

Comment: But i think this would return every messages sent and received by this user.
``````
``````
messages:{
    id:{
        message: 'abcd'
        senderid: '123'
        receiverid: '321 } }
``````
Considering the above model, I want to only the messages between these two ids only

Comment: then query the senderid

Comment: That would return all the messages sent by that id. I want the messages that were sent and received by that id to some particular id